# How do I draw multiple things on a Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, object, canvas, drawing

I am fairly new to HTML Canvas. This is such a noob question, but why doesn't this code work?

```
window.onload = function() {
    const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    const c = canvas.getContext("2d");

    c.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 200, 0)";
    c.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
    c.fillRect(50, 100, 100, 100);
}
```

All I am trying to do is get there to be two rectangles on the canvas... A big green one and and a smaller black one. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, what you're doing is drawing two green rectangles. As the second one is inside the first one, you don't see it. You're missing setting the `fillStyle` property to black after drawing the green rectangle:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas1');
    var c = canvas.getContext('2d');

    c.fillStyle = 'rgb(0, 200, 0)';    
    c.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
    c.fillStyle = 'black';
    c.fillRect(50, 100, 100, 100);

}
```

Comment: Oh my gosh! Thank you!
I've never used stack overflow, and it's nice to see someone responded so quickly. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome. Please, mark the answer as corrent then.

Comment: Err, how do I go this?